# For which item slots are Warforged Items not available?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to know which item slots do not have the potential to receive ***Warforged*** or ***Heroic Warforged*** Gear.

I know that the 2 slots I listed under 'Cosmetic' Slots cannot contain them, but what about the others?

I have only seen *Warforged* versions of all the Main Slots, as well as Wrists and Neck Slots.

Below are the Item Slots:

#### Main Slots (Could be set pieces):

- Head Slot (Helm)
- Shoulder Slot (Spaulders)
- Chest Slot
- Hands Slot (Gloves)
- Legs Slot

#### Sub Slots:

- Back Slot (Cloak)
- Wrists Slot
- Waist Slot (Belt)
- Feet Slot (Boots)

#### Jewelery Slots:

- Neck Slot
- Ring1 Slot
- Ring2 Slot
- Trinket1 Slot
- Trinket2 Slot

#### Weapon Slots:

- Main Hand (Also for Two-Handed)
- Off-Hand

#### Cosmetic (Barely Functional) Slots:

- Shirt Slot
- Tabard Slot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warforged Items are available for every slot except for the cosmetic ones (Tabard and shirt).

However Tier Sets as well as the Legendary cloak cannot be warforged. If you take a look at the [most equipped players on WoWprogress](http://www.wowprogress.com/gearscore/) you will see that there is a Warforged version of almost every item.

The Warforged status is not limited by slots but rather by Items.